# Cycle Through Syntax Coloring in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to write a syntax coloring script for a programming language I'm writing a compiler for, but to minimize the work required (as I barely know vimscript) I would like to find a coloring script that produces colors that are close enough to what I want to be able to just edit that script.

What is the best way to have Vim show me a specific code file and then apply every single different syntax coloring script it knows, so that I can determine which is closest? So far I've been using

```
:set syntax=<the next syntax script>
```

but is there anything easier, or less repetitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cycle through all your syntax scripts by applying the following steps:

1: Find all your installed syntax scripts and store them in a variable

```
:redir @a
:echo glob($VIMRUNTIME . '/syntax/*.vim')
" Hit G
" Hit Enter
:redir END
```

2: Open a new buffer in vim and paste your scripts from the register 'a' by typing in command mode:

```
"ap
```

3: This will output all your syntax scripts (excerpt from the first lines of my 1205 installed ones)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/2html.vim
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/a2ps.vim
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/a65.vim
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/aap.vim
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/abap.vim
```

4: Cut these by using [Visual Block Mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#CTRL-V), so that the result looks like this (again omitting ~1200 lines):

```
2html.vim
a2ps.vim
a65.vim
aap.vim
abap.vim
abaqus.vim
abc.vim
abel.vim
```

5: Now strip away the ".vim" ending by applying the following Regular Expression:

```
%s/.vim//g
```

Now they will look like this:

```
2html
a2ps
a65
aap
abap
abaqus
abc
abel
```

6: Save the result into a buffer. From there you can use this script to cycle through all of them:

```
v$h"*y:set syntax=^R*^Mdd
```

Or, in order to color all the open windows, use `:windo set syntax=...` instead of `:set syntax=...`.

Explanation:

1. mark the first syntax name

   > v$h
2. yank/save the name under the register * 
     "*y*
3. set the syntax in command mode
     :set syntax=
4. delete the last checked syntax name

   > dd
5. If you [save this script in a macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros), you can cycle through them using @@

Enjoy(;

Comment: Thanks, but when I `:set syntax=...` it only changes the syntax coloring for the buffer that contains all the syntax-script names. How can I change the syntax coloring for _all_ buffers open in Vim?

Comment: @feralin If you have all buffers open in the same window, it is easy: :windo set syntax=...

Comment: Also, why is `V` not valid as a replacement for `v$h`? It does the exact same thing when I run it...

Comment: It's also swallowing the Return character in the end of the line. V works for me, too, but I wouldn't count on it that it works for all OSs, therefore I feel better with v$h.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using colorschemes (read more about them using ":h colo"). You can list all your installed color schemes by using this command:

```
 :colorscheme <ctrl+d>
```

Those you can copy to a buffer and cycle through them. If you want to go the easy way, there is a script ready that provides that functionality: CycleColor, a script to cycle through (almost) all available colorschemes: https://github.com/vim-scripts/CycleColor

Comment: I know about colorschemes, and that's not what I'm asking about. I want to cycle through syntax highlighting scripts, not through color schemes. For example, I would like to see what my file looks like with python coloring applied, or ruby coloring applied, or C coloring applied, etc.; I already know what colorscheme I want.

Comment: @feralin Ok, so here it goes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276689/cycle-through-syntax-coloring-in-vim/25292763#25292763

Comment: @feralin It took some time to write that code, so please be nice(;